# How to escape special words in oracle?

Tags: special-characters, oracle9i

I have the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE FOR_DELETE([DATE] DATE )
```

but it seems that there is a difference in escaping special words as INT, DATE and so on and its not like in SQL... How to escape special word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard SQL would use double-quotes ("), and some implementations may use backticks (`). Out of the top of my head, Oracle will take the double-quotes.